# Get events clicking a day in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to know if is possible to get a list or array or something with events of one day by clicking that day in fullcalendar.

Now I get the events from google calendar, if I need to make a query each time I want to get events of one day, it will be so hard for connections. I guess it has to be possible since you already have the events for rendering them.

One user ask me for code:

```js
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    console.log(date);
    console.log(allDay);
    console.log(jsEvent);
    console.log(view);

    if (allDay) {
        // alert('Clicked on the entire day: ' + jsEvent);
    }
},
eventClick: function(event) {
    if (event.url) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can't understand why someone voted me negative. I made a question, someone ask for code, I put code but I EXPLAINED why I have no more code, and -1 vote? I can't understand it.

Comment: Please post some code of what it is you have tried or are attempting to do.

Comment: I don't have code since I don't know if it is possible or not. I just have a function (I will post right now) about dayClick, but I cannot see any events in console.

Comment: Code added. I don't know if inside these 4 parameters I can find events. I open them in console and I couldn't find anything. I don't know if I can add other parameters for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you could do something like

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
  var dayEvents = $('yourSelector').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents' function(event){
    return event.start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) === date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    //or some way to compare that is the same day
    //I recommend momentjs lib ex moment(event.start).isSame(date,'day')
  });
}
```

What I suggest is to query the client events and filter it checking if its the same day

Comment: Thanks man. What is clientEvents? Do I have to change that variable too?, Will the return give me every single event of that day?

Comment: var dayEvent = $calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
    return +event.start.startOf('day') == +date.startOf('day');
   });