# How to know how many events are available in same time in jquery full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am new to jquery full calendar

[how to know how many events are bind at same time in jquery full calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6UXY.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read **[how to ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and improve the quality of the question.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this fullcalendar [method](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) where you can add a filter for searching event (e.g. by date).
examples:

- [Get events clicking a day in FullCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523905/get-events-clicking-a-day-in-fullcalendar)
- [fullCalendarjs method fullCalendar('clientEvents') returns duplicate events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987278/fullcalendarjs-method-fullcalendarclientevents-returns-duplicate-events)